# How can hide horizontal scrolling on dbgrid in Delphi

Tags: delphi, scroll, dbgrid

How i can hide or remove scrolling by horizontal on dbgrid in Delphi7. I have try by changing width onResize but its not correctly way.

Comment: Do you want to hide the ScrollBar or resize the colums so that the ScrollBar is not shown?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
EnableScrollBar(DBGrid1.Handle,SB_HORZ,ESB_DISABLE_BOTH);
ShowScrollBar(DBGrid1.Handle,SB_HORZ,False);
```

The problem is that disables the scroll, but it displays  :-(

Other option is:

```
TDBgrid2 = class(TDBgrid)
  private
    procedure WMNCCalcSize(var msg: TMessage); message WM_NCCALCSIZE;
  end;
  .
  .
procedure TDBgrid2.WMNCCalcSize(var msg: TMessage);
var
  style: Integer;
begin
  style := getWindowLong( handle, GWL_STYLE );
  if (style and WS_HSCROLL) <> 0 then
    SetWindowLong( handle, GWL_STYLE, style and not WS_HSCROLL );
  inherited;
end;
```

It is more complicated, but it is the perfect solution.

Comment: If you opt for the second solution, also remember to change the class in the .dfm file

Comment: I have a problem with this - the client area where the scrollbar used to be is not clickable -> can't select the bottom row

Answer (score 2):

A followup to the David's perfect solution. You don't have to change the class in .dfm if using same type names

```
  TDBgrid = class(DBGrids.TDBgrid)
  private
    procedure WMNCCalcSize(var msg: TMessage); message WM_NCCALCSIZE;
  end;
```